# Comparsion between PostgreSQL timestamp without timezone and java.util.Date with timezone

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, hql

I would like to know how the comparsion in the following query will be performed:

```
StringBuilder queryStr = new StringBuilder();
queryStr.append("SELECT o FROM PRDBook as o WHERE ")
        .append("o.publicationDate < :now");

Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryStr.toString());
Date now = new Date();
query.setParameter("now", now);
```

In the database, column `publicationDate` has type `timestamp without time zone`. Sample value in this column:

```
2018-03-01 18:00:00
```

The result of `now.toString()` is:

```
Wed Aug 22 16:14:03 CEST 2018
```

Will the comparsion between mentioned data be performed in that way:

> *2018-03-01 18:00:00 < 2018-08-22 16:14:03*

or that way:

> *2018-03-01 18:00:00 < 2018-08-22 14:14:03*

Comment: A `java.util.Date` does not have a timezone; it's just an abstract point in time.  Have you tried running your code to see what actually happens?  So, I vote for the first version being what will happen.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have run the code having a book in database with publication date 2018-08-22 16:58:17. The value of now was Wed Aug 22 16:59:11 CEST 2018. The mentioned book object has appeared on the result list. So it seems, that you voted correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question.

When PostgreSQL's JDBC driver reads a column of type `timestamp without time zone`, it can usually read it to a `java.sql.Timestamp` or `java.util.Date`.

If you choose to read it to a `java.util.Date` (your case) PostgreSQL's JDBC driver automatically adds the local JVM time zone to it. That makes sense since the whole point of a column of type `timestamp without time zone` is to be treated as a "local" timestamp.

Conversely, when you send a `java.util.Date` to the database it strips down the time zone right away. Therefore the query condition will take the form:

> 2018-03-01 18:00:00 < 2018-08-22 16:14:03

Collaterally, this means **it's recommended you set the JVM time zone explicitly**, to make sure the JDBC driver is reassembling the database `timestamp without time zone` into a `java.util.Date` the correct way.

Otherwise, different servers in different time zones reading the **same** row in the same database will interpret that timestamp as a different moment in time. Nevertheless, this should probably not be a valid use case for an application that uses "local" timestamps.

Comment: When you are talking about "automatically adds the local JVM time zone to it" or "strips down the time zone" do you mean just adding timezone information, but without any additional timestamp conversion like it happens between different time zones(for example database UTC time on read is converted to local timezone time)?